# css menu lateral no funciona

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, label

estoy creando un menu lateral, al hacer click en el icono de las barras me mustra el menu y al hacer click en el icono de la equis me lo oculte.
El problema es que al hacer click en el icono de la equis no funciona, me sigue dejando el menu desplegado. He intentado de todas las formas posibles, no se que error estoy cometiendo en el chekcked, la clase que lo tiene no me funciona.
He visto algunos tutoriales y el problema sigue igual, hasta actualice la pagina para ver si asi se resuelve el problema.
quieo saber que hago mal.

```
introducir el código aquí <div class="menu">
  <nav class="menu--nav">
    <div class="menu--nav__bars">
      <label for="check" class="fa-solid fa-bars"></label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" class="menu__check">
    </div>
    <div class="menu__xmark">
      <nav class="menu__list">
       <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Categorias</h2>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
       <h2>Tecnologia</h2>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
       <h2>Vehiculos</h2>
       <label for="check" class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></label>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
       <h2><a href="">Electrodomesticos</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Hogar/muebles</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Deportes/fitness</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Belleza y cuidado personal</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Construccion</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Herramientas</a></h2>
       <h2><a href="">Internacional></h2>
        <h2>Moda</h2>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <h2><a href="">Juegos/Juguetes</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Bebes</a></h2>
        <h2><a href="">Agro</a></h2>
        <h2>Accesorios</h2>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <h2><a href="">Animales/Mascotas</a></h2>
        <h2>Equipaje</h2>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Supermercado</h2>
        <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Restaurante</h2>
        <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Eventos</h2>
        <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Servicio al cliente</h2>
        <h2 class="menu--nav__list">Mensajes</h2>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

```css
.fa-bars + .menu__check{
    display: none;
}

.fa-bars:hover{
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-bars:active{
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__xmark, .menu__list{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: #f2f3f4;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.menu__check:checked, .menu__xmark, .menu__list{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.menu__xmark, .menu__list{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    bottom: 37%;
    max-width:198px;
    background-color: #c1c1c5;
    transition: all 400ms  ease;
}

.menu--nav__list{
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 52px;
    padding: 10px;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transform: translatey(10px);
    border-left: 10px, solid, transparent ;
}

.menu--nav__list:hover{
    color: #000;
    left:0;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    border-left: 10px solid, #f8f9ff ;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}

.fa-xmark{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 235px;
    left: 90.4%;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.fa-xmark:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.fa-xmark:active{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Comment: Te hace falta eso mismo, indicarle que debe hacer el menú cuando le des clic. eso lo lograrás empleando Javascript. Ya que tu codigo hasta ahora es CSS y HTML

Answer (score -1):

Para ocultar el menú cuando se hace clic en el icono de la equis, deberías agregar una **clase de CSS que oculte el menú** cuando se haga clic en el icono de la equis. Puedes hacerlo agregando una clase de CSS como "hidden" al elemento del menú y luego utilizando la regla de CSS **"display: none"** para ocultar el elemento del menú cuando se agregue la clase "hidden".

Por ejemplo, podrías agregar la siguiente regla CSS a tu hoja de estilos para ocultar el menú cuando se agregue la clase "hidden" al elemento del menú:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Luego, cuando se haga clic en el icono de la equis, puedes agregar la clase "hidden" al elemento del menú para ocultarlo. Por ejemplo, si tu elemento del menú tiene un ID de "menu", podría agregar la clase "hidden" al elemento del menú de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById('menu').classList.add('hidden');
```

Esto agregará la clase "hidden" al elemento del menú, lo que causará que se oculte gracias a la regla de CSS que definió anteriormente.

Si deseas mostrar el menú de nuevo cuando se haga clic en el icono de las barras, puede utilizar la misma lógica para remover la clase "hidden" del elemento del menú. Por ejemplo, podría remover la clase "hidden" del elemento del menú de la siguiente manera:

```
document.getElementById('menu').classList.remove('hidden');
```

De esta manera, cuando se haga clic en el icono de las barras, se removerá la clase "hidden" del elemento del menú y se mostrará de nuevo.

[Te dejo esta guía como referencia](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-modificar-atributos-clases-y-estilos-en-el-dom-es)